# How to grab content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have such HTML node:

```
<div id='parent'>
   <a href="#">test</a>
   Need this
</div>
```

How to get 'Need this' text if I have handle for `parent` object?
I tried something like: `$('#parent').text()` but it also returns 'test'.

---

p.s. **Nothing** about editing html! I just have such content and I need to parse it.

Comment: Why don't you wrap your text in a paragraph tag or a span tag. It would much easier then trying to get that text.

Comment: @Nick look at update, please.

Comment: The help page  for .contents() gives an example for " Find all the text nodes inside a paragraph and wrap them with a bold tag." that might get you started down the right path... http://api.jquery.com/contents/ I figure that's not useful enough to actually be considered an "answer"... :-)

Comment: So grab the text `$('#parent').text();' and use a regular expression to strip the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that the text content is always the last content in the div, you can do:

```
$('#parent').contents().last().text();
```

on this markup:

```
<div id='parent'>
   <a href="#">test</a>
   Need this
</div>
```

**Returns:** *Need this*

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/64RVf/

Answer (score 6):

```
var temp = $('#parent').clone();
temp.children().remove();
alert(temp.text());
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/H6jQp/

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

```
$('a').click(function(){
   alert($(this).parent().clone().find('a').remove().end().text());
});
```

here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/RTqyy/

probably not the best way, i'd wrap that text in a div or span or p.  but this will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $text = $("#parent").contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType != 1; });
alert($text.text());
```

Seems to do the trick. ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JfSvd/))