# Jquery Selector, Do NOT include an anchor inside a p tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I got one of these:

```
$('a.retweet').click(function () {
    var retweetText = $(this).closest('.article-content').children('p').text();
}
```

With a bunch of these:

```
<p><a href="">Name</a> stuff written here </p>
```

But I just want the text inside the `p` tag and NOT the `a href`.  So how do I just get the text in the `p` tag?

Comment: This questions sounds exactly like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916338/how-to-grab-content

Comment: It is pretty much an exact duplicate.

Comment: ...And asked not an hour ago. CloseHammer, activate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `);` in that function. Try this --

**jQuery**

```
$('a.retweet').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var retweetText = $(this).closest('.article-content').children('p').text();
    alert( retweetText );     
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="article-content">
    <a href="#" class="retweet">Testing</a>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G8MfP/

Answer (score 1):

If the text will always be the last child in the element, use `.lastChild.nodeValue`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the markup, so that the text you want is in a `<span>`:

```
<p><a href="">Name</a> <span>stuff written here</span> </p>
```

the problem is trivial to solve:

```
$(this).closest('.article-content').children('p').children(':not(a)').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.retweet').click(function() 
{
    var retweetText = $(this).closest('.article-content').children('a').text();
}
```

Comment: That gets exactly the opposite of what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$('p').contents().last().text();
```

So you'd have:

```
$(this).closest('.article-content').children('p').contents().last().text();
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This will return the textNode

```
$(this)
  .closest('.article-content')
  .children('p')
  .contents()
  .filter(function() { 
    return this.nodeType == 3;
})
```

This should return the text of that node.

```
$('a.retweet').click(function () {
    var retweetText = $(this)
                        .closest('.article-content')
                        .children('p')
                        .contents()
                        .filter(function() { 
                          return this.nodeType == 3;
                        }).text();
}
```